# Storing image in base64 format in MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to store images in base64 format in MongoDB. What should I return to React frontend? Would buffer be enough?

Comment: I may be missing something but why not to return the base64 data to your frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return base64 to the frontend and render it in the browser. For example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```